# Как переделать дизайн zsh?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh

Решил сделать терминал прозрачным и все иконки наложились друг на друга и стали другой формы.
Как заново сделать дизайн zsh?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: nvim alacritty.yml

Comment: exec zsh И после этого я перешел в настройки дизайна терминала. Все было хорошо, но уже после, когда я создал новый профиль и поставил авто подключение к alacritty (Preferences ->'мой профиль'-> Command -> Custom Command) и там вбил zsh для авто подключения при запуске терминала. Я просто хочу переделать дизайн при помощи zsh в терминале

Comment: то есть удалить старый дизайн и создать новый также командой exec zsh